# PHP. Function preg_replace_callback with create_function() because PHPversion 5.2

Tags: php

I want to replace identical `<IMG>` tags in a string with an array with different values.
So IMG, IMG will be:

```
<IMG src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AA ....etc> , <IMG src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AA ....etc >
```

Since the pattern has to be mixed with `preg_replace()`, and because `preg_replace_all` doesn't exist, i have to use the function `preg_replace_callback()`.

I have PHP version 5.2 so i have to use a `create_function()` within `preg_replace_callback()`.

Does anybody have an idea how `preg_replace_callback()` has to look like in this situation?
I cannot understand how `create_function` works. Do i have to make a loop or something?

My code with `preg_replace()`: This changes all IMG tags with the first picture of the array. But i need loop through all the IMG tags with `preg_replace_callback()`/`create_function()` and replace with different pictures of the array.

```
$artikelinhoud = $simpleXml->StandaardOplossing->attributes()->ArtikelInhoud;
$arrayImages = array();
preg_match_all('<!\[(CDATA)\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]\]>', $artikelinhoud, $arrayImages);

$images = array(); 
foreach ($arrayImages[2] as $key => $image) {
    $images[$key] = 'src="data:image/jpg;base64,' . $image . '"';   
}

$imagesOld = array();
$imagesOld[] = '/type="(.*?)"/';

$artikelinhoud = preg_replace($imagesOld, $images , $artikelinhoud);
```

Variable `$imagesold` is always the same. And `$images` is an array with different values to put between tags.

The array `$images` looks like:

```
[0]=> string(26464) "src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4A...etc
[1]=> string(23464) "src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4A....etc
```

Greetz, Eric

Comment: The way you worded your question will be hard to help you... I think you shouldn't need to use regular expressions, maybe you just need to use DOM and XPath for that... :)

Comment: yes maybe, but i am almost at a solution. The string is a big html string with a few times IMG tags in it. The only problem now is every image tag in the string is replaced with the first image of the image array. And not with different images. So i will be happy with the golden tip :-)